# (How) can I run a bare machine with a disk from an runnable machine?

Tags: backup

Suppose that I have a machine and it runs into some severe problems and no longer functions, then to save the data and the environment I ripped the hard disk from the broken machine and plug it into a new bare machine with no hard disk. I cannot run it directly, but I don't know why and if I have any opportunity to save the soft system.

Comment: If you copied all the partitions, perhaps only grub is missing, you can try to restore it by following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/454520)

Comment: It should boot right up. If it does not it suggests the hard drive has failed or has problems.

Answer (score 0):

As a first stage to recovering a crashed system I would suggest booting the new machine with a bootable USB or CD/DVD and taking a look at the contents of the recovered drives.

[Here is a tutorial on making a bootable USB stick](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)